# jmeter JDBC insert capture autogenerated id

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I have a table with auto generated id column

```
create table table1 (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name varchar(100)
)
```

And I run a JDBC sampler with the following update statement

[image: jmeter-jdbc-insert]

A row is inserted as expected. Is there a way I can get hold of the autogenerated id, like using `PreparedStatement#getGeneratedKeys` in JDBC?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as of [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html), the alternative way I can think of is using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) instead of JDBC Request sampler and implement the [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) yourself.

You can acquire the [Connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) object from the pool defined by the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) as:

```
def connection = org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection("your JDBC pool name")
```

if you need to return query results to other test elements you can use `vars` shorthand to [JMeterVariables class instance](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) like:

```
vars.put('id', 'some id from the result set')
```